# How to use ipywidgets.Dropdown in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

When I use `ipywidgets.Dropdown` in Jupyter Notebook, the option box is not rendered.

[image: Code screenshots here]

```
from ipywidgets import widgets

function = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=[('one',1), ('two',2)], 
    value=1,
    description='function')
function
```

All I got was:

```
Dropdown(description='function', options=(('one', 1), ('two', 2)), value=1)
```

but no dropdown choices.

I also tried `display(function)`, didn't work either.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Hmmm...your example code is working fine here in both relatively current classic notebook interface and JupyterLab. Have you restarted the kernel and run the cells again?

Comment: Yes, it's probably related to your environment. You can try to enable ipywidgets using `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension` or `jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension` if you're using conda environment.

If this doesn't work try to clear jupyter's cache.